# What is "team 2v2", how it differs from "random 2v2" and how to enable it?

Tags: starcraft-2

I noticed that there is a "2v2 team" (3v3 team, 4v4 team) section in the "leagues and ladders -> friends" in addition to "2v2 random". It is my understanding that what I've been playing is "2v2 random". What is that "2v2 team" ladder?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

'2v2 random' mean that you will randomly be put on a team for each ladder match.

And '2v2 team' is where you are partnered up with someone and you stay their partner throughout the ladder. Most commonly a friend. The only way I believe to set this ladder up, is to have your partner be in your party before starting a 'Quick Match'. You will get placed in different ladders with different friends, meaning you can be placed in several '2v2 team' ladders.